# Inject service or class in guard in NestJS

Tags: apache-kafka, dependency-injection, nestjs, guard

Needs to DI Kafka client in guard:

auth.guard.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  private _client: ClientKafka; <----- // TODO implement nestjs DI mechanism

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      
      const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      const authorization: string = request.get('Authorization');
      ...code here just send data to jwt service...
    
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I use *new* in canActivate for creating an instance of Kafka client in auth.guard.ts. But how to inject a class in guard with @Inject? I used to create @Global module, which provides and export Kafka client class, but it's not working...

Comment: Is this the case [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#binding-guards) under the notes for global guards with dependency injection (by using `provide: APP_GUARD`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This in the module for globally using the guard

```
providers: [{provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: AuthGuard}]
```

As for your question about injecting a class inside a guard, you need to inject it inside the constructor of the AuthGuard class

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private clientKafka : ClientKafka){}
}
```

if this doesn't work, try using

```
constructor(@Inject(private clientKafka : ClientKafka)){}
```

Hope this resolves your issue :)